# How to provide a groovy script from git repository to set Extended Choice Parameter

Tags: jenkins, extended-choice-parameter

[image]As mentioned in the screenshot, I have a groovy script which can give us the values. But I want to keep this script in a git repository to for version control. There is an option "Groovy Script File" but it taken local file path. Even in documentation, it is shown to be taking path like /tmp/file.txt. How to pull this file from git to provide choice parameters for the plugin.